# cannot hide php extension in .htaccess file on godaddy

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

Hello this is my code of .htaccess file . i have tried so many     codes to hide the code but none id working please help me .. this is my full htaccess file.this hide code i found little bit good but this is showing my page content.

```
     Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
     # Turn mod_rewrite on
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /

      ## hide .php extension
      # To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
      RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
      RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

   ## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]


    ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mydomainname.com/
    Options +FollowSymLinks


     #Disable directory browsing       
     Options -Indexes

  RewriteEngine on

 #Redirect non-www to www   
 RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}    ^mydomainname\.com$
 RewriteRule     (.*)    http://www.mydomainname.com/$1    [R=301,L]


RewriteRule pages/(.*) page.php?page=$1

RewriteRule blog/(.*) blog.php?type=$1

 RewriteRule post/(.*)/(.*) post.php?pid=$1&name=$2

 RewriteRule news-and-events/(.*)/(.*) news.php?nid=$1&name=$2 

   i found many code but none is working
```

Comment: How do you link the pages? .htaccess does't automatically hide the extension. You have to put the link without extension like `<a href="page/mypage">my page</a>`

Comment: i try like this  <a href="page/mypage">my page</a> but now how will it redirect to mypage.php  if i use only mypage in a tag

Answer (score 0):

Use this `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: i have try this , this working only on index page ,other pages are hiding but page content is not showing